# Understanding how Attitude Indicator works?

Tags: flight-instruments

[image]

Hi guys. The only doubt I have is if the roll and pitch gimbals shown on the top rotate or remain rigid in space holding the gyro when the airplane is pitched and/or banked. I think that they remain in the same position and the only thing that moves is the instrument case as shown on the bottom picture, what do you guys think?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The extremely fast spinning gyro remains in the same orientation in space as the instrument case moves around along with the instrument panel and the whole aircraft. The difference between the orientation of the gyroscope and the casing is mechanically or electronically transformed to display the orientation of the plane

The stabile orientation of the gyro is achieved by the gimbals: each axis has its own gimbal that will allow (almost) frictionless movement with respect to that axis. However the gimbals are actually not free to do what they want so to speak. They are dependent on each other by stacking: each axis/gimbal is dependent on a higher level one that it attaches to. This will in some instances lead into an interesting situation called gimball lock. This video describes the phenomenon:

Answer (score 0):

> I think that they remain in the same position and the only thing that moves is the instrument case as shown on the bottom picture...

The instrument reading is directly derived from a gyroscopically-leveled, essentially precession-free, gimbal-mounted sensor.  There is no binding of the freely moving instrument sensor within the instrument case.  This excellent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykwJI-7W-c4) by Ryan Anderson explains clearly the operation of the freely-moving instrument sensor.  Take a look, one should have no doubts...